# AccessDeniedException: 403 when trying to copy file to Google Storage from VM using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I’m trying to manually do the steps I need to automate the process to understand how it works and to make sure I get all the commands straight. But when I try to do it using the command:

`gsutil cp file_name gs://bucket_name/`

I get the following error:

`AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient OAuth2 scope to perform this operation.`

It was supposed to be a very simple thing, but I can't get it right. I'm used to do it in AWS, but I'm not being able to do the same in Google Cloud. Anyone knows how to get over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the account you're using to attempt this copy doesn't have permission to write an object to the `bucket-name` bucket.

If you're doing this on a GCE VM and using its default service account, make sure that you selected the correct access scopes when creating the VM -- the default scopes include read-only access to GCS. You can check this by logging into the VM and using `curl` to query the GCE metadata server:

```
$ curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes"
[...]
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
[...]
```

Comment: Oh wait, now I got confused. Is the problem here that my account that does not have the permissions or the problem is that the GCE VM does not have the permissions? And yes, just checked and the VM is read only for the Storage.

Comment: The error message only relates to the oauth token scopes requested, which is controlled through "read only for storage" for the VM. If it were a problem with the account permissions, you would get an error like "'userxyz' does not have 'storage.objects.write' to 'object_name'"

Comment: I see, thanks. I was talking with a friend that uses Google Cloud and we got it figured out creating a service account. I will post an answer talking more about it. It is some sort of user permission that even when the VM is read only for storage it can do the thing

Answer (score 2):

This error has nothing to do with read/write permissions, but with scope assigned to your compute instance. In other words, you need to grant it right to use GCP resources at all, read/write permissions for particular object is what you do next.

Previously it was necessary to recreate instance, but now it is enough to stop and then run below command, for example using cloud shell:

```
 gcloud compute instances set-service-account myinstance \
     --service-account 192893587797-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
     --scopes cloud-platform
```

Of course replace `myinstance` and `192893587797-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
with your own `compute instance` and `service account name` accordingly.

Comment: FWIW, this was what worked for me. I'd been assuming IAMs take precedence over scopes, but you need at least this scope in place. If you use a custom service account, possibly with a custom access role, then you'll need to be careful with scopes to make it all work.

Answer (score 2):

Hey @Marcus Vinicius Melo,

I was the project owner and still facing the same issue. After I install gcs python package, it solved. Try pip install google-cloud-storage

Comment: This answer worked on FreeBSD 12.2 (fully patched), gcloud 312.0.0 gsutil 4.53.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I tackle this problem, may be helpful for new users here:

Step by step process without deleting the existing VM:

1. Stop the VM instance
2. Create a new service account **IAM & Admin** > **Service Accounts** > **Add service account**
3. Create a new service account with the full permission as (**project > owner** )
4. Create **private key** for this service account
5. After creating the new service account, go to **vm** and **click on it's name** > then  click on **edit**
6. Now, in the editing mode, scroll down to the **service-accounts** section and select the new service account.
7. Now, access it via the **in-browser ssh** and you will be good to go!
8. Here's the command I used to copy files to bucket: `sudo gsutil cp FILE_PATH gs://<BUCKET>`

Answer (score 1):

I talked to a friend of mine and he helped me solve this, and here is the solution:

My GCE VM has read only permissions for the Google Cloud Storage. I found in web that you can only change this status when you create the GCE VM, and that in order to overcome this I would need to create a new one and delete this VM. That would work, but I didn't want to go loose everything I've done in my current VM.

The other solution that worked for me was to create a service account (Google Cloud Platform > IAM & admin > Service Accounts). You just need to give it the service account name you want, and select 'Furnish a new private key'. Then you should be good to go. After that I could copy files from GCE VM to Storage and do everything else I needed.

Comment: Do I have to give this key to my VM or something? Because just generating a new key and doing nothing else didn't solve this for me.

Comment: I don't quite remember right now, it was a while ago, but you need to assign this account to your VM or something like that

Comment: I ran into this problem after deleting a default service account and then re-adding it. I had to still go to Service Accounts -> Actions -> Create Key before it would work (even though it had been granted the expected permissions - still needed the key before it could use those permissions, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Marcus Vinicius Melo you just need to enable Storage Transfer API in GCP then gsutil for a GCE to bucket will be done.

Comment: From Review: Please improve the explanation in this answer. Also please avoid any informality. Otherwise, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question.