# 403 Insufficient OAuth2 scope to perform this operation

Tags: google-app-engine, bucket

I have a Google cloud vm instance that has a directory in a persistent disk that I want to transfer over to a bucket.  I'm using the command

```
gsutil cp -r directoryname gs://my-bucket
```

but it keeps giving me the error

AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient OAuth2 scope to perform this operation. 
Acceptable scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

the vm instance has all Clouod API's enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AccessDeniedException: 403 when trying to copy file to Google Storage from VM using gsutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346311/accessdeniedexception-403-when-trying-to-copy-file-to-google-storage-from-vm-us)

Answer (score 3):

In order to execute this operation, your instance should be having an access to the cloud storage write operation. You can [view service account, access scope and change access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) of the VM instance from which you are trying to execute this command. Alternatively, you can [create a new service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#createanewserviceaccount), given it appropriate IAM permission and assign to VM instance. Moreover, you can view authorized account for the VM by ["gcloud auth list"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) command and login an account by ["gcloud auth login"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)